# Question about the partitioning during installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

During the installation of Ubuntu 14.04, should I locate the "boot" partion after or before the "swap" partition, and what should I choose for the "boot" partition "primary or logical","at the beginning of the space or the end"?

Comment: Short answer: nowhere, and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose either of them.

Comment: I believe the person already knows they can choose either. It would be helpful to explain the differences and maybe some pros and cons so the OP can make a better informed decision.